# AutoMapper mapping not working properly JObject/Json

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map JObject to POCO class using Automapper, It mapped only same name property and ignore method does not work.

I'm not sure AutoMapper support Json to POCO class mapping or Is it an issue with my configuration?

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

        string json = File.ReadAllText("jsonData.json");
        JArray assets = JArray.Parse(json);
        List<AssetDTO> assetDTOList = Mapper.Map<List<AssetDTO>>(assets);
    }
}

public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<AssetProfile>());
    }
}

public class AssetProfile : Profile
{
    public AssetProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JObject, AssetDTO>()
            .ForAllMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());

        CreateMap<JObject, AssetDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AssetId, o => o.MapFrom(j => j["AssetId"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, o => o.MapFrom(j => j["AssetType"]))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DeviceSerialNumber, o => o.MapFrom(j => JArray.Parse(j["Device"].ToString())[0]["SerialNumber"]));
    }
}

public class AssetDTO
{
    public string AssetId { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

jsonData.json

```
[
{
"AssetType": "Paver",
"AssetId": "PaverId100",
"ContactName": "ContactName",
"Description": "description",
"Device": [
  {
    "Make": "BP02",
    "SerialNumber": "BPPA0001",
    "Ucid": null,
    "Address": {
      "AddressLine1": "address 1",
      "AddressLine2": "add 2",
      "City": "city",
      "State": "B'lore",
      "ZipCode": "124578",
      "Country": "India"
    }
  }
]
}
]
```

[Github](https://github.com/PankajRawat333/JsonToPoco) repo for sample code

Comment: Remove those maps. See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html).

Comment: I don't want to auto map (by matching name) and I have some property which I want to map explicitly.

Comment: You can do that, but then your map will have to handle everything. AM doesn't know anything about JObject, it will handle it just like any other type.

Comment: Yes, I want to write all mapping manually. I'm trying JObject first time with automapper.

Comment: Remove that first map. See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I resolved this. The issue I observed that Jarray does not work like List and Array, so I iterated over JArray and convert each JObject to POCO.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

        string json = File.ReadAllText("jsonData.json");
        JArray assets = JArray.Parse(json);
        List<AssetDTO> assetDTOList = new List<AssetDTO>();

        for (int i = 0; i < assets.Count; i++)
        {
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(assets[i].ToString());
            AssetDTO assetDTO = Mapper.Map<AssetDTO>(jObject);
            assetDTOList.Add(assetDTO);
        }

    }
```

[Github](https://github.com/PankajRawat333/JsonToPoco) repo for sample code